# Understanding BILOU tagging in vowpal wabbit

Tags: machine-learning, named-entity-recognition, vowpalwabbit

I'm at a loss currently as to why my simple BILOU tagger is not working using VW and was hoping I could get some insight into why.

I'm trying to predict a tag for the following train.txt and test.txt files

**test.txt**

```
1 | the
7 | United
8 | States
8 | of
9 | America
1 | agreements
1 | is
1 | hereby
1 | voted
1 | as
1 | established

1 | the
7 | United
8 | States
8 | of
9 | America
1 | is
1 | great

1 | the
7 | United
8 | States
8 | of
9 | America
1 | is
1 | happy
```

**test.txt**

```
1 | the
7 | United
8 | States
8 | of
9 | America
1 | is
1 | big

1 | the
7 | United
8 | States
8 | of
9 | America
1 | is
1 | good
```

according to https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/blob/f032eaf50086b6814ae1169e633620b2b05bfd47/vowpalwabbit/search_sequencetask.cc#L77 my assumption is the labels

7 -> B-Country

8 -> I-Country

9 -> L-Country

now when I run my training:
which I found https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/blob/f032eaf50086b6814ae1169e633620b2b05bfd47/test/RunTests#L1066

```
vw -k -c -d train.txt --passes 20 --search_alpha 1e-8 --search_task sequencespan \
    --search_span_bilou --search 9 --holdout_off -f data.model
```

I get the output:

```
final_regressor = data.model
switching to BILOU encoding for sequence span labeling
Num weight bits = 18
learning rate = 0.5
initial_t = 0
power_t = 0.5
decay_learning_rate = 1
creating cache_file = train.txt.cache
Reading datafile = train.txt
num sources = 1
average    since      instance            current true      current predicted   cur   cur   predic    cache  examples
loss       last        counter           output prefix          output prefix  pass   pol     made     hits    gener  beta
2.000000   2.000000          1  [1 1 8 8 9 1 1 1 1 ..] [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ..]     0     0       11        0       11  0.000000
2.000000   2.000000          2  [1 1 8 8 9 1 1       ] [1 1 1 1 1 1 1       ]     0     0       18        0       18  0.000000
1.000000   0.000000          4  [1 1 8 8 9 1 1       ] [1 1 8 8 9 1 1       ]     0     0       32        0       32  0.000000
0.500000   0.000000          8  [1 1 8 8 9 1 1       ] [1 1 8 8 9 1 1       ]     1     0       71        0       71  0.000001
0.250000   0.000000         16  [1 1 8 8 9 1 1       ] [1 1 8 8 9 1 1       ]     3     0      149        0      149  0.000001
0.125000   0.000000         32  [1 1 8 8 9 1 1       ] [1 1 8 8 9 1 1       ]     7     0      305        0      305  0.000003
0.062500   0.000000         64  [1 1 8 8 9 1 1       ] [1 1 8 8 9 1 1       ]    15     0      617        0      617  0.000006

finished run
number of examples per pass = 4
passes used = 20
weighted example sum = 81.000000
weighted label sum = 0.000000
average loss = 0.049383
total feature number = 2340
```

and the testing command which I took from https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/blob/f032eaf50086b6814ae1169e633620b2b05bfd47/test/RunTests#L1073

`vw -d test.txt -t --search_span_bilou -i data.model -p pred.txt`

my *pred.txt* file seems to be missing my B tag and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

```
1 1 8 8 9 1 1
1 1 8 8 9 1 1
```

My assumptions are that since the sentences are very similar there shouldn't be much learning that needs to take place. And that I'm just trying to get a basic example up and running to start from.